# How to wrap three divs in one in order to share background?

Tags: html, css

I'm making a small website, I created the `div`s but now I have a question, I have one div "header" and next to that that, I have two divs side by side, I want to wrap that 3 divs in one container.

I tried some things I saw, but until now isn't what I want.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  width:100%;
}

body > div {
  height: 200px;
  padding: 50px;
}

.header {
  background-color: grey;
  height: 50px;
  color: white;
}

.product {
  margin-top:0px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  float:left;
  width:50%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

.product2 {
  height: 500px;
  margin-top:0px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  width:50%;
  float:left; 
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

.crew {
  clear:both;
  background-color: tomato;
  color: darkgrey;
}

.tour {
  background-color: black;
  color: darkgrey;
}

.pricing {
  background-color: gold;
  color: black;
}
.contact {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

.menu{
  margin-top: 4%;
  margin-right: 5%;
  font-size: 18px;
  list-style:none;
  float: right;
}

.menu li{
  display:inline;
  float:left;
}

.menu li a{
  color:blue;
  text-decoration:none;
  padding:6px 23px;
  display:block;
}

.menu li a:hover{
  background-color:none;
  color:red;
}
```

```html
   

     <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
      <title> Layout </title>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <div class="header">
      <img src="logo.png">
      
      <ul class="menu">
     <li><a href="#">Home &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a> </li>
        <li><a href="#">Product Tour&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a> </li>
        <li><a href="#">Pricing&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a> </li>
        <li><a href="#">Try&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Vision</a></li>            
       </ul>
    </div>
    
    
      <div class="product">
      </div>
      <div class="product2">
      </div>
      <div class="crew">
      </div>
      <div class="tour">
      </div>
      <div class="pricing">
      </div>
      <div class="contact">
      </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

How can I wrap the first 3 divs into one?

Comment: Can you explain clearly what is your expected output or give screenshot.

Comment: Chris, i need to share the same background between the 3 divs, my ideia is to join them and then set the background to the div joining them.

Comment: "*i wrap the first 3 divs into one ?*" means in which container? You need first three `header`, 'product` and `product2` side by side ?

Comment: Yeah, just put a div tag around it and you're done, your problem is most probably have it to look like you wish (which we can't guess without a sketch) than "wrapping" them...

Comment: can you show your expected output as image?

Comment: Maybe i didnt use the right terms, i tought wrap and join was the same thing. I want the layout as it is right now, but that 3 divs inside one, i created a new div with the 3 divs inside, but all i got is a blank space.

Comment: @BugaDroid like http://jsfiddle.net/njatf18y/1/ way?

Comment: Yep, But with the grey bar at top and the other two divs bellow side by side.

Answer (score 2):

Please edit your css as Shown below. You will get the design as ur need. All the best

```
.menu {
    float: right;
    font-size: 18px;
    list-style: outside none none;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.menu li a {
    color: blue;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.menu li {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    padding-right: 23px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the backgroundfor lots of objects you can:
1. Give them all the same class rather than an id e.g.

```
<div class="divclass" id="div1"></div>
<div class="divclass" id="div1"></div>
<div class="divclass" id="div1"></div>
```

**OR**

2.Wrap them all in a div just put them in div tags both sides
e.g.

```
<div id="bigdiv">
   <div id="div1"></div>
   <div id="div2"></div>
   <div id="div3"></div>
</div>
```

3. style the body tag (in css)

   body {
        background:red;
   }

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Use `display:inline-block` for bottom `product` and `product2` div and add first 3 div inside another main div.

HTML:

```
<div class="main">
<div class="header">
    <img src="logo.png"/>

  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Home &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a> </li>
    <li><a href="#">Product Tour&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a> </li>
    <li><a href="#">Pricing&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a> </li>
    <li><a href="#">Try&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Vision</a></li>            
   </ul>
</div>

<div class="sub">
  <div class="product">
  </div>
  <div class="product2">
  </div>
 </div>  
</div>
```

Check [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/njatf18y/3/)

Comment: My goal is to that 3 divs fill whole yellow space or main div.

Comment: @BugaDroid it's becuase you have margin. I will make it Check http://jsfiddle.net/png10kmh/1/.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I got it how i wanted. But now how should i do fill the divs with same background ? Thanks again